# Identity Server 4, getting "invalid_client" error in auth 2.0 (authorization) workflow

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4, and need to give my users access to other side. I have configured my application in third party site for SSO, so my application is acting as service provider for that third party website with auth 2.0 flow.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ClientId",
                ClientName = "ClientName",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("secret".Sha256())}, 
                AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.AuthorizationCode},
                RedirectUris = new List<string> { "https://pubhive.myfreshworks.com/sp/OAUTH/312319274297315477/callback" },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                },
                 AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                 AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                RequirePkce = false,
                AllowPlainTextPkce = false,
                  AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                 AccessTokenLifetime = 60*60
            }
```

My Api sources

```
  new ApiResource("ClientId")
            {
                Scopes = new List<string>{ IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email},
                UserClaims = new List<string>{ StandardScopes.Email},
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>{ new Secret("PubhiveAPISecretKey777".Sha256()) }
            }
```

Following Auth 2.0 flow from postman:

[image: img1]

And getting "invalid_client" error as showin in Image below

[image: img2]

The request shown below (also tried with adding client_secret) :

[image: img3]

gives me same "invalid_client" error and now I am stuck with this, auth flow is without pkce.

Comment: I will try your configuration in my local setup its working fine please check you put only the wrong secret or clientId

Comment: could you send curl request ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is alright. You should click "get new access token" at bottom first. Then use this token for further test.   Dont't click "Send" for getting a token.
[image]

Comment: This ClientId and secret in image is dummy data, I have checked actual one and they are correct. Sorry for wrong info in image.

Comment: @AkshitVaghela I modified my answer. I only reproduce this error when click "send" instead of "get new access token".

Answer (score 0):

ClientId, clientSecret and scopes are case sensitive so they have to match exactly with your client config.